# How to use DeclareSourcemap to add default value to a field

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to use Biber sourcemaps to add a default value to bibliography items' `hyphenation` field if there isn't any (I want the default hyphenation for bibliography entries be different from the document's main language). This is the best I could come up with:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=needs-hyphenation,fieldvalue=true]
      \step[fieldsource=hyphenation,fieldset=needs-hyphenation,null]
      \step[fieldsource=needs-hyphenation,fieldset=hyphenation,fieldvalue=british]
      \step[fieldset=needs-hyphenation,null]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to conditionally process entries in a sourcemap based on the *absence* of a key. The `fieldsource` in itself can be used to make a step conditional on the *presence* of a field, which I (ab)use to bring a "flag" field into existence then conditionally delete it.

Is there a better way to conditionally run a step if a field is *not* present?

Comment: How about `\step[fieldsource=hyphenation, notmatch=".", final]`? This will only continue if the field is blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry guys, the realisation came to me the second I posted this question! :-)

`\map` without `[overwrite]` will not overwrite any fields, therefore one can just say

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=hyphenation,fieldvalue=british]
    }
  }
}
```

and not worry about overwriting anything. However, I do wonder if this "flag field" method of programming is of any use in some other situation...